# String to date conversion in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime, strptime

I'd like to convert such a date '2012 30 March 9:30 pm' into this format 2012-03-30 09:30:00
What is the easiest way to do that? I need it to be working on PHP 5.2 and older, so this solution isn't of any use for me

```
date_format('Y-m-d H:M:S',date_create_from_format('Y m F g:i A', '2012 30 March 9:30 pm'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will extract each component from the date and rearrange it so that `strtotime()` understands. Convert to any date format you want after that.

Using regex is probably overkill though.

```
function parse_date_time_to_ts($dt) 
{
    $dt_pattern = '#([0-9]{4})\s+([0-9]{1,2})\s+([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})\s+(am|pm)#is';
    $dt_replace = '$2 $3 $1 $4 $5';

    return strtotime(preg_replace($dt_pattern, $dt_replace, $dt));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EDIT: following Stewie advice:

<?php

list($year, $day, $month, $hour, $minute, $ampm) = sscanf("2012 30 March 9:30 pm
", "%d %d %s %d:%d %s");

if($ampm == 'pm') $hour += 12;

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($day . ' ' . $month . ' ' . $year . ' ' . $ho
ur . ':' . $minute));
```

Comment: This won't work, the date format isn't standard unless the user is using some alien locale

Answer (score 1):

Use sscanf(), then make the string in the correct format, strtotime() on it and then date() with the format required.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#106043

see the link of official documentation and an user contribution...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list($year, $month, $day, $year, $hour, $minutes, $a) = sscanf("2012 30 March 9:30 pm", "%d %d %d $s $d:$d $s");
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($day." ".$month." ".$year." ".$hour.":".minutes." ".$a));
```