# PHP String to date conversion

Tags: php, date

I'm about to pull my hair out people. I've got a form where people select a day and a month from the dropdown menu, and the current year would automatically get concatenated.

On the server I've got this:

```
$received =  date("Y")."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
$date = strtotime($received);

$newformat = date('Y F j',$date);
echo $newformat;
```

Let's say `$_POST['month'] == 'April'` and `$_POST['day'] == '5'`

The output always comes out like this:

`2013 April 1` (ie the day defaults to 1).

Interestingly if `$_POST['day'] == '24'` then the output is:

`2013 April 2`

It's as though it just looks at the first digit.. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you verified what `$received` contains?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to date conversion in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720356/string-to-date-conversion-in-php)

Comment: Yes - if I do `echo $received;` I'll get `2013-April-5` - correct output..

Comment: @remyabel - it makes no difference. If I do `$newformat = date('Y-F-j',$date);` I get the same thing - `2013-April-1`

Comment: Drop the dashed in the $received format and see if that helps.

Comment: @user1775598 The problem lies in your handler and/or your form (I don't see full code here). I've tested it and I get perfect results. When I entered "5" for month and "24" for day, I get `2013 May 24`. Check your syntax in your form and your handler.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613732/problem-with-date-and-strtotime & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101605/strtotime-date-weird-behaviour-when-converting-date-in-to-same-format-as-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your issue that your "Month" variable is a string instead of an integer, but you are putting it in the date as if it's an integer?  `2013-April-5`...  Try just putting in a `4` instead of `April`.

**Update**

To answer your question, you can have your client updated to have options like `<option value="1">January</option>`, or update your PHP to process it like:

```
<? $received =  $_POST['month']." ".$_POST['day']." ".date("Y");
$date = strtotime($received);

$newformat = date('Y F j',$date);
echo $newformat; ?>
```

I think that will work.

Comment: I think you're right! On the client side the dropdown shows the month as a string - `January, February, etc`. When the form gets submitted `$_POST['month']` is the value of the dropdown which comes in the form of a string. Is there any way to convert that into a date without having to convert the month to an integer?

Comment: @user1775598 Updated my answer to help.

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks! Was the problem that I set `$received` var with dashes inside or was it the order in which I `month`, `day` and `year` came? Or both?

Comment: @user1775598 I'd say it was an issue of both.  Dashes wouldn't be used when spelling out the month so PHP wouldn't understand the format.  Glad I could help though, and don't forget to mark this as the answer if it fixed your problem for future visitors.  Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lie in your handler and/or your form (without seeing full code in your question).

I've tested it and I get back perfect results.

When I entered `5` for month and `24` for day in the form I build below, I get back `2013 May 24`.

Check your syntax in your form and your handler.

In using the following form and handler, I get perfect results

HTML form

```
<form action="date_handler.php" method="post">
Month: <input type="text" name="month">
<br>
Day: <input type="text" name="day">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP handler

```
<?php
$month=$_POST['month'];
$day=$_POST['day'];
$received =  date("Y")."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['day'];
$date = strtotime($received);
$newformat = date('Y F j',$date);
echo $newformat;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I think the problem is that the `$_POST['month']` var was a being parsed as a string instead of an int. Now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create a date using a string for the month so that I don't have to convert it to an int.

Comment: @user1775598 You're welcome. Can you post your full code? Maybe there's something in there that's breaking it.